# setTimeout with mongodb each

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I am writing some code that calls DuckDuckGo's API, constructing the querystring using data from a mongoDB collection. I want to pause for a few seconds before each API call, so as to not hit the server too frequently. This is my code, however, I find that after waiting for a second, all the API calls are made immediately.

What mistake am I making / how can I write this so that there is a one second pause between each call?

```
collection.find({}).each(function(err, item) {
    if (item === null) {
        db.close();
    } else {
        setTimeout(function() {
            var req = http.request({
                host: 'api.duckduckgo.com',
                path: '/?q=' + item.letters + '&format=json&pretty=1'
            }, callback).end();
        }, 1000);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about something like this:

```
var i = 1;
collection.find({}).each(function(err, item) {
    if (item === null) {
        db.close();
    } else {
        setTimeout(function() {
            var req = http.request({
                host: 'api.duckduckgo.com',
                path: '/?q=' + item.letters + '&format=json&pretty=1'
            }, callback).end();
        }, 1000*i);
        i++;
    }
});
```

Here, `i` represents the index of the request. You just multiply the wait time (in this case `1000`) by the index to make each additional request take longer than the previous one.

Comment: Thanks - this worked. Why didn't the simple setTimeout work? Shouldn't the loop have iterated only after the timeout?

Comment: @appa yes, but the thing is that there is one timeout for each element of the collection, and all of these are created roughly at the same time (the `.each(...)` loop does not wait for the timeout to fire before going to the next item).

Answer (score 0):

you can use [setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval) in order to execute your code with fixed time delay between each call instead of [setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout), as:

```
collection.find({}).each(function(err, item) {
    if (item === null) {
        db.close();
    } else {
        setInterval(function() {
            var req = http.request({
                host: 'api.duckduckgo.com',
                path: '/?q=' + item.letters + '&format=json&pretty=1'
            }, callback).end();
        }, 1000);
    }
});
```

Comment: Tried this, but this didn't work - it behaved exactly as the setTimeout.