# Update data in MongoDB Model in intervals

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mern

I am making a login system. I am trying to make user wait for 5 minutes when login attempts exceed 3 times, here is the `User Model`:

```
const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  // Other Model Schemas
  loginAttempts: { type: Number, default: 0 },
});

//Functions - Other functions above

// I am trying to make user wait for 5 minutes when login attempts exceed 3.
// But this is not working.

if (this.loginAttempts > 3) {
  setTimeout(() => {
    this.loginAttempts = 0;
    this.save();
  }, 1000 * 60 * 5);
}
if (this.loginAttempts >= 1) {
  setTimeout(() => {
    this.loginAttempts = 0;
    this.save();
  }, 1000 * 60 * 60 * 60 * 1);
}

const User = mongoose.model("User", UserSchema);
module.exports = User;
```

I was searching `UserSchema.<parameter>`, I was searching parameters or function (sorry I don't know the exact term) which works like `setTimeout()` or `setInterval()` which checks on model and updates data like I have tried in above `if(){}` statement.

Can anyone suggest me a function in Schema which checks on intervals and update data as the time runs out just like, `setTimeout` function and `setInterval` function

Comment: I think this might help you:- [setTimeout with MongoDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28710378/settimeout-with-mongodb-each)

Comment: There is ready open-source solution for auth protection. You can use [RateLimiterMongo](https://github.com/animir/node-rate-limiter-flexible/wiki/Mongo) from [rate-limiter-flexible](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rate-limiter-flexible) package. There are many examples on [Wiki](https://github.com/animir/node-rate-limiter-flexible/wiki/Overall-example).

Answer (score 0):

use [rate-limiter-flexible](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rate-limiter-flexible)!.
I hope this package is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

You can create a new schema called exceededUser and create an TTl (time to live)

```
const ExceededUser = new mongoose.Schema({
  userId: { //your userId type },
  createdAt: { type: Date, default: Date.now(), expires: 60 * 5 },
});
```

What this `expires` do is, it delets itself after 5 min.

When you login you first check if your userId is saved inside this exceededuser collection.

1. If yes, return error that user needs to wait (that means the TTL of 5 min arent over an it didnt deleted itself yet).
2. If no, then try to log in.

   1. If credentials are correct, reset `loginAttempts` to 0
   2. If credentials are not correct, increase `loginAttempts` by 1

      1. If `loginAttempts` is 3, then save "exceededUser" with your user ID, reset login attempts and return error that he exceeded.
      2. If `loginAttempts` is less then 3, just return normal error that credentials are wrong

Comment: Sorry @bill.gates its not working.

Comment: @RaghavPatel then u probably did it wrong

Comment: thanks for reply. Yes you were right but you gave me an idea thank you so much I will share the answer soon.